# Getting unexpected token error in appium doctor

Tags: appium

I have installed appium doctor and got it installed without error on mac. However when I used command "appium-doctor -h" to check. It gives following exception. Can you please let me know what is going wrong here:

```
appium-doctor -h
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-doctor/build/lib/general.js:59
catch {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-doctor/lib/factory.js:3:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-doctor/bin/appium-doctor.js:4:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue related to the node version, please try to install the latest version of the node recommended version from below link

[Node Latest Version v12.13.0](https://nodejs.org/en/)

I am also facing the same issue, once upgraded to the recommended/latest version of the version node problem solved.

If not resolved post the error here will do further debugging.

Comment: Thank you , it resolved the issue now appium doctor commands are running fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Run these commands it will solve the issue:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
- curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
- source ~/.profile
- nvm ls-remote
- nvm install v12.16.2
- nvm use v12.16.2
- node -v